# How do I disable the Mac startup sound?

Tags: sound, startup, mac

The "bong" sound Macs make when starting up are very annoying. Although they serve a purpose as a POST confirmation, I'd rather not have it alert everyone in the room.

There are ways to either quiet or turn off the sound in OS X, but that's not something I currently have access to, nor am I willing to install.

Is there anything I can do?

Macbook 2006

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: It's related to Ubuntu because Ubuntu is installed on the Mac, and therefore the question asker cannot use OS X to disable the startup sound.

Comment: The OP asked about the Macbook 2006, but I'd prefer the most generic answer possible.

Comment: Can you please add the exact model of your macbook (output of `sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name`)? Also on my macbook the volume of the startup-sound corresponds to the normal system-volume - if i set it to 0, then there's no startup-sound.

Comment: @Clausi - I don't know about the OP, but in my case it's `Macmini6,1`. (Hence wanting a generic answer, if possible.)

Answer (score 2):

Late reply but:

1. Reboot with an OSX installation disc or Recovery HD
2. Start the Terminal
3. Issue the command:

   ```
   /usr/sbin/nvram SystemAudioVolume=%01
   ```

Comment: does this work when you do not have MacOS installed along side and only Ubuntu?.. because it's still doing the chiming after applied your instruction above..

Answer (score 2):

I found this in the Arch-Wiki. [Link to ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/mac#Mute_startup_chime)
It should also work for Ubuntu and other distros in theory.

1. Gain sudo privileges with

   ```
   sudo -su
   ```
2. Remove immutable bit from the efi variable that controlls the Startup Sound / Chime to make it editable

   ```
   chattr -i /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/SystemAudioVolume-7c436110-ab2a-4bbb-a880-fe41995c9f82
   ```
3. Set that efi-variable to 00 to disable the startup sound

   ```
   printf "\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00" > /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/SystemAudioVolume-7c436110-ab2a-4bbb-a880-fe41995c9f82
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I just now thought of this. I did a bit of research on it and I didn't find anything specific, but I think that you could disable it via rEFit boot manager.

I have rEFit on my iMac to swtich between OSX and Windows 7 and it has all sorts of tools for boot options and partitioning. I think you might be able to do it through it since it uses the EFI or "BIOS" directly and you should be able to install it through Ubuntu according to the site. I'll do some more searching around and testing if I can and edit my answer as it applies, but for now here is the link for rEFit:

http://refit.sourceforge.net/

EDIT:

rEFind as suggested in comments. rEFind is currently maintained:

http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

Comment: rEFIt is old an no longer maintained. You should use [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) instead. I use it to efi boot Ubuntu on a Macbook Air 5-2.

Comment: That is correct, rEFit is no longer maintained, It's just what I personally have experience in so that's why I suggessted it, but rEFind might be the better choice seeing as it is currently maintained and is pretty much the same program, either way though the same result should be able to obtained if it is possible at all to do it via the EFI.

Comment: I boot directly from the Apple bootloader. No rEFIt/rEFInd.

Answer (score 0):

Well, normally, on a PC, you would have BIOS, but on Apple you have that EFI which is their equivalent. The Extensible Firmware Interface can be opened by:  press Command-Option-O-F keys during startup. If there is no way to disable the sound there, well, not much else I can offer in terms of assistance. Would state that the issue is a Mac hardware issue with EFI, not so much of an Ubuntu issue.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me on a Mac Mini Mid 2011:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mac#Mute_startup_chime

Run the commands as root and start with chattr -i as explained in the wiki. Try at your own risk.